# How to convert a NSString to UTf8string for using multiple languages?

Tags: android, iphone, objective-c, utf-8, nsstring

I am using two languages in my project i.e English and Turkish.There is a Registration from.For Registration form i am using Web-services.If i am sending data in the text-field in English language.it is going fine as exact as in English.But when i am sending the text in Turkish language,the text which i am sending is changed to some other text in the database.Why it gets happen in the Turkish language.
This is the problem i am facing .Please provide me some code,so that i can solve this problem.

Comment: so are you developing your project for Android and iphone simultaneously?

Comment: Why have you tagged `Android` here?

Answer (score 0):

In my case which is arabic I used:

```
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

you can edit to apply your case if needed.